E2E tests for AWS eventbridge API destinations
We have an API to register a member for our e-commerce application and in the back of that API we have multiple eventbridge rules that are configured to target different API destinations.
One of the API destination is to send a set password email with a link to a page of the client application with a token and expiration time of the link. The email is sent via AWS SES.
I am trying to write an E2E test for this flow but its a bit difficult to integrate with the client application so what are the options for me to write an E2E test for this email flow?
Few options that I have considered:

Using a seperate email client called mailslurp or testmail to receive the email but from what I have read is that this solution is very flaky and error prone

Somehow make a conditional call in the API to send the request to another API to fetch the link instead of sending an actual AWS SES email. This seems more of a better solution but I am not sure how I can handle that in the code.

Stub about the whole email flow (But this leaves a blind spot and only as a last resort)


I am sure this is a common use case and I would like to know how others have solved it.
